# Instagram API Error: Client request limit reached

Tags: api, instagram

I am getting this error whenever I try to follow someone on Instagram via API no matter how many follows have been done before:

```
{"meta":{"error_type":"APIError","code":400,"error_message":"Client request limit reached"}}
```

My app allows authenticated users to follow interesting people. I know that there is a 5000 call/hour limit per authenticated user, but it fails even with new users. 
Do my app is reaching some kind of client level limit?

Comment: for what api are you getting this error ?

Comment: POST /users/user-id/relationship  action=follow

Comment: Not sure, new user should be able to follow, i known each type of api has different limits, likes/follow is 200/hr i think, 5000/hr limit is for all api.

Comment: 1.) Are you sure this is a valid token?
2.) Are you sharing the token with any other apps?
3.) Are you sending more than one request in short period of time?
    - Like some buggy code that does somehow causes requests to get fired back to back

Comment: Does the Token have the right scope? See http://instagram.com/developer/authentication/#scope

Comment: @hharnisc 1) Yes, the token is valid because I can use it in other type of API calls. 2) No 3) Maybe because I can't control how my users use the app. They can do any number of actions.

Comment: @Tobi Yes, I have the right scope. As I mentioned I can do follows until I get limited.

Comment: I have the same problem with POST api.instagram.com/v1/media/{media-id}/likes. First I sent request to it every 10 seconds. After almost 70 times I got this Message : {"error_type":"APIError","code":400,"error_message":"Client request limit reached"}}. I waited for about 2 hours but it didn't get fix. So I created a new client and get new client_id and client_secret and regenerated a new access_token. Set the request interval to 5 minutes. but again after about 60 request I got bad request. I think Instagram bans my client for some reason. I don know what to do!

Comment: @aartiles I am also seeing this "Client request limit reached" error on a brand new Client I setup with no previous requests made. Not sure if it takes a while for new Clients to become "active". I have tried issuing the same requests from an older client I had already setup, under a different Instagram account and it works fine, so it's definitely a new Client thing...

Answer (score 1):

APIs like follow, unfollow, comment are limited to 350 requests per hour. However sending requests from client side will fix this problem to some extent but it allows the users to see your API token.

Comment: Is the "350 requests per hour" limit public anywhere? Anyway I experiment limits of 30 follows/day, and after a couple of hours all users of my apps see the limit.

Answer (score 0):

In this case it looks like it would be beneficial to get some more data from your users. You could use Google analytics to track the "follow" action

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide

This would give you a timestamp and information about user behavior.

Even with an advertised rate of X requests per hour, one user hammering the service with your API key can cause everyone to get throttled. (Not guaranteed, but pretty common practice for companies to keep their services alive)

It might be a good idea to reset your API, its possible (though unlikely) that someone has acquired your key and is using it.